# How to set default value in yaml translation?

Tags: symfony

In Symfony 5 there are a folder messages, in it messages.en.yaml that have translation:

```
product
       description:  This product is {title}.
```

In the code user call for translation `$this->translateMessage($message, ['title' => 'Title translation']);`

Does Symfony have any possibilities to set default value in messages.en.yaml for {title} value if it will be null?

Comment: Do you mean something like `home.hello: Welcome on %project_name%` where you could simply call `$translator->trans('home.hello')`, and variable %project_name% would be injected automatically ?

Comment: @VictorWeiss I mean, in case home.hello: Welcome on %project_name% if %project_name% will be null from $translator->trans('home.hello'), then I want to show default value.

Comment: i guess you would rather use sth like `->translateMessage($message, ['title'] => $title ? $title : $default_title])`